# Area of rectangle composited from other rectangles in relation to their perimeters proof help

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

I've been trying to brush up on my geometry recently and got this problem which I'm not sure how to prove exactly. The explanation of the problem is as follows.

> The sum of the perimeters of the blue and yellow rectangles is 104cm. The perimeter of ABCD is 80cm. Find the area of the rectangle ABCD.

[image: rectangle diagram]

So what we know from the condition is this.

$$ P_{ABCD} = 2(AB+BC) = 80cm $$

$$ P_{blue} + P_{yellow} = 104cm $$

From that we can get the difference

$$ (P_{blue} + P_{yellow}) - P_{ABCD} = 104 - 80 = 24cm $$

And now maybe that's a very stupid question, but I'm having trouble describing what do these 24cm denote exactly?

I'll explain my chain of thought, but I'd love some pointers or explanations on any parts that are wrong. My reasoning is that 24cm here is actually the shared side of the blue and yellow rectangles which in essence is

$$ 24cm = BC * 2 $$

If my reasoning is correct from that we can actually get both sides of ABCD

$$ P_{ABCD} = 2(AB+BC) = 80cm $$
$$ (AB+BC) = \frac{80}{2} = 40cm $$
$$ BC = \frac{24}{2} = 12cm $$
$$ AB + 12 = 40 $$
$$ AB = 40 - 12 = 28 $$

And with this we can get the area of ABCD

$$ S_{ABCD} = AB \times BC = 12 \times 28 = 336cm^2 $$

Is this actually correct based on the way the problem is framed? Is my reasoning valid or not? What could be made better (if it's correct)?

Comment: Hint: Label the 2 points E and F, then write $P_{blue}$ explicitly. $\quad$ Your conclusion of $BC = 12$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can note that the sum of the perimeters of the yellow and blue regions is equal to the perimeter of $ABCD$ with the 'middle line' counted twice more. This middle line is simply $BC$, so phrasing this in terms of the equations, we have $$
P_{blue} + P_{yellow} = P_{ABCD} + 2BC = 104cm $$
We also know $P_{ABCD} = 80cm$. From this we easily find $2BC = 24cm$ or $BC = 12cm$. Because the perimeter of $ABCD$ is equal to $2(AB + BC) = 2(AB + 12) = 80$ we just solve for $AB$ to find $AB = 28$. Finding the area is now just multiplying $AB\cdot BC = 28\cdot 12 = 336cm^2$.